# Exception in python not producing expected result

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an exception in python:

```
to_addr = input("Enter the recipient's email address: ")
print("To address:", to_addr)
from_addr = 'cloudops@noreply.company.com'
subject = 'Welcome to AWS'
content = mail_body
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = to_addr
msg['Subject'] = subject
body = MIMEText(content, 'html')
msg.attach(body)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpout.us.companyworld.company.com', 25)
try:
    server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=[to_addr])
    print("Email was sent to: %s", to_address)
except:
    print("Email was not sent.")
```

What happens is that the server.send_message function works correctly. It sends the email and I receive it.

But the exception prints its statement.

This is my output:

```
Enter the recipient's email address: tdunphy@company.com
To address: tdunphy@company.com
Email was not sent.
```

Also I am excepting for all errors. How can I find common errors to look for if I am unfamiliar with the errors a command produces? So that I can put them in the exception.

Comment: Stop using that blanket `except`, and you would see a nice exception message telling you what's actually going wrong. Probably `to_address` not existing. (The line before that uses `to_addr`, not `to_address`.)

Comment: I do get the email. So the to_address exists. Should I show more of my code?

Comment: @bluethundr I think he is referring to the `to_address` variable which you are using in the first print after you send the mail. What we think it happens is that the mail is sent and than an `undefined` exception is thrown when evaluating `to_address` from the first print

Comment: I've updated my code to show the whole function.. Grazi.

Comment: @bluethundr no it doesn't, you are only using it within the print statement, the actual `to_address` is `to_addr` which u used a line before the print statement

Comment: I've updated the OP to show all of my code. And I've added this print statement that shows to_addr exists. This is my output now: `Enter the recipient's email address: tdunphy@company.com
To address: tdunphy@company.com
Email was not sent.`. And I do get the email.

Comment: @bluethundr There is still no defination for `to_address` variable

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. The to_address variable is not defined. When I print out the exception this is what I see: `Exception:  name 'to_address' is not defined`

Comment: @bluethundr If my answer was helpful u can upvote it, if it did fix the problem u can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On second line you are using `to_addr` variable, while on third line you are using `to_address` variable

probably `to_address` is undefined

Since you except the error, u can't trace it

Consider catching `Exception` and assign it to a variable like `e`

```
try:
    server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=[to_addr])
    print("Email was sent to: %s", to_address)
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e)) # it can be a logging function as well
    print("Email was not sent.")
```

Also u need to change `to_address` to `to_addr` like this so the except block won't execute:

```
try:
    server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=[to_addr])
    print("Email was sent to: %s", to_addr)
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e)) # it can be a logging function as well
    print("Email was not sent.")
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply let it propagate and then check in the console what the specific class of error you have or you could do the following:

```
class MyE(Exception):
    pass

try:
    raise MyE()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
```

which will yield: `<class '__main__.MyE'>`

The reason why your exception is caught is because of an undefined variable (`to_address`).

Consider the following example:

```
try:
    print("yes")
    print(some_undefined_variable)
except Exception as e:
    print("no", e)
```

which will yield:

```
yes
no name 'some_undefined_variable' is not defined
```

which means both of the `try/except` were called and failed when evaluating the non-existing variable.